# What is the difference between arithmetic shift left and logical shift left?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I know that arithmetic shift right preserves the MSB and logical shift right doesn't. But what is the difference between **arithmetic shift left and logical shift left**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same operation. Both shift the bits to the left and adds a '0' to the LSB.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of arithmetic shift is to preserve the MSB.

In the case of a left shift, arithmetic and logic shift do the same operation.

In the case of a right shift, arithmetic shift preserves MSB and rest of the bits are shifted right

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift#Equivalence_of_arithmetic_and_logical_left_shifts_and_multiplication)